# Autofill not working on non username and password

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill, next.js

I am trying to understand the different between chrome autocomplete, autofill, and why me new form won't do one of them. My original login form is very old and in regular HTML. As you can see if I click userid or password it brings up my chrome autofill for usernames and passwords. 
[image: https://puu.sh/Dp5Qv/6d8ddfb9f5.png]

Notice the ability to "Manage passwords" at the bottom. This is working just fine on my form. Now notice if I click on the customer id, it does not autofill via my passwords, it instead suggests what I think is "autocomplete" via chrome

[image: https://puu.sh/Dp5Tc/d36bb8c052.png]

This is not working on my new form which is using next-js. I have the same structure and attributes on my forms and inputs as best I can tell. And like I mentioned before, chrome autofill for usernames and passwords is working just fine. Any idea why the other type of autocomplete would not be working?

Comment: It would be nice to see your code